# return updated records from sql stored procedure bulk updation

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an stored procedure with follwoing code.

```css
 update c set
  earnings = conUpdate.earnings,
  member = conUpdate.member,
  employer = conUpdate.employer
 from contribution c
 inner join  @ContributionUpd as conUpdate on c.contribution_id=conUpdate.contribution_id
```

Is there any way to return updated records from storedprocedure.
And i am using sqlserver 2012

Answer (score 2):

The Output clause could be helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms177564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396